# How to document function methods and prototypes from within IIFE using JSDoc

Tags: javascript, prototype, iife, jsdoc3

I have struggled to try and figure out a good way of doing this, but to no avail. Maybe someone here can help me document an IIFE like the following

```js
var module = (function(){

  var main = function() {
    return Object.create(main.prototype);
  };
  
  main.foo = function() {};
  
  main.prototype.foo = function() {};
  
  return main;
}());
```

Module can then be used like jQuery where you can call `module()`, `module.foo()` or `module().foo()` and I need to document all of those calls clearly.

Edit: Specifically, what JSDoc annotations can I use to document the public API of this module? I've tried mixtures of @namespace, @module, @alias and @memberof and either the prototype functions do not show, or they do, but they are indistinguishable from the primary functions.

Comment: So your question is how to document your public api?

Comment: @Icepickle Yes basically.